# Populating ASP.NET SqlDataSource from a Firebird 2.0 Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, firebird, sqldatasource

I am working on a project where I do not have any control over the versions of products that I have been asked to work with.

I am building an ASP.NET user control. Data is retrieved via `SqlDataSource` controls working against Firebired 2.0 databases. Everything was fine until I needed to populate one of the `SqlDataSource` controls via a stored procedure rather than a `SELECT` statement.

I have verified that the procedure is returning data in EMS SQL Manager for Interbase and Firebird. However, when I set the `SqlDataSource`'s `SelectCommand` property to `EXECUTE PROCEDURE myProc` and call `Select()`, I am getting no data.

My procedure takes no input parameters so it seems to me that it should be straight-forward.

The reality of the situation is that I could use a simple `SELECT` statement if I were able to move to even 2.1 as I would have access to the `List()` aggregate function, but that is not a possibility.

Does anyone have any experience trying to do this? Does the procedure call need to be modified in any way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is selectable stored procedure (it has `SUSPEND` command in it) then you should call it with `SELECT` statement, not with `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` statement. So set your `SelectCommand` to

```
SELECT * FROM spName
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much!!  I feel silly for not thinking to do it that way :).  All data returned and working perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do this like so (against SQL Server) :

```
// set the SqlDataSource's SelectCommand to the *name* of the stored procedure
myDataSource.SelectCommand = "myProc";

// tell the SqlDataSource that this is a *stored procedure* now
myDataSource.SelectCommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Since your stored procedure takes no input parameters at all, this should really be all!

With SQL Server, selecting the data works just fine with this setup.

Comment: Thanks marc_s.  I tried that and I am getting a dynamic sql error from firebird

Comment: Sorry ... I posted that too fast and wasted my edit :).  My error looks like this:

Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 1
myProc

so I think it needs to be called with the EXECUTE PROCEDURE, just as I would within Firebird ... when I did it originally, I got no data but I also got no error, and it looks like it's the name of the stored procedure that it is choking on.

I can get the data just fine using the FB client classes. For now I'll populate a view I am binding to a grid that way but want to use the DataSource so I can use its caching features.

Comment: @burghboy: OK - sorry, I don't know Firebird well enough to really be of help on that topic.